# mysql - compare the timestamp field only with the year and month

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

Company table:

[image]

Now I want to find the following:

(1)
Joindate start with December. 
My expected output: 
[image]

(2)
Joindate start with November and end with December.
[image]

How do I compare the timestamp field only with the year and month?

Comment: use `YEARWEEK()`, `YEAR()` and/or `MONTH()`

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,join_date
from tab
where month(join_date) in (11,12) and year(join_date)=2015
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is specify what the month is with `MONTH()` (I would recommend using `BETWEEN` since its a built in method for date and number comparison) and the year with `YEAR()` and then order the final results in a descending manner

```
SELECT stuff
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(date) BETWEEN 11 AND 12 
  AND YEAR(date) = 2015
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f407/1)**